# statistical analysis of data with qq plot

Tags: statistics

I have generated qq plots to show how my observed distributions differ from the expected ones. Is it possible to assign some statistics to this plot (e.g.: p-value)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are assuming normal distribution then you can choose your favorite test among; Anderson-Darling, Shapiro-Wilk, Jarque-Bera and Kolmogorov-Smirnov. If it is a non-normal distribution, thus I'm aware only of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic\test.